# Trying to get property of non-object ({{$perfil->id}}) - Laravel Error

Tags: php, laravel

I have this controller function:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $perfil = DB::select('SELECT * FROM tb_perfis WHERE id='.$id.';');
    return view('perfis.show')->with('perfil', $perfil);
}
```

This view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{$perfil->id}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And i get the error:

```
"Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/alexandre/Documents/PAP Hidroponia/pap/resources/views/perfis/show.blade.php)"
```

Why is this happening, in other pages has no problem.

Comment: Have you verified that `$perfil` actually has a proper value? Maybe your query returns an empty result set / null.

Comment: What @Xatenev said - make sure the query is returning data. Also, that query is vulnerable to SQL injection, so you should address that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve the query like this

```
$perfil=DB::table('tb_perfis')->where('id','=',$id)->First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query builder is missing `->get()->first()` at the end.

However, it should be something like:

```
$perfil = DB::table('tb_perfis')->where('id', $id)->get()->first();
```

When you use raw select statements, you are responsible to prevent SQL injections.